# Recycler view not showing up

Tags: android

So I am querying a firebase database, and trying to read the data into a recyclerview. Now when I simply read the data into a textview and set the text to the data, (i.e. I have 3 text views - colour, height, name) this all works fine and the correct data shows up.

However, I've been trying to load the query results into a recycler view, rvResults, and it just won't work. I am adding the data into arraylists, and then passing the arrayLists (Colours, Heights, Names) containing the query results into my ResultsRecyclerAdapater. However, when I run I am getting a blank screen - but no crash.

I'm no expert, but this block seems to be the problem. It doesn't seem to be adding these into the arrayLists. My 'Plant' class is all fine, so that's not the problem.

```
String name = plant.getName();
                        String bio = plant.getBio();
                        String height = plant.getHeight();
                        String colour = plant.getColour();

                        names.add(name);
                        heights.add(height);
                        colours.add(colour);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> heights = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> colours = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    Task task1 = plantRef.whereEqualTo("height", "Medium")
            .get();

    Task task2 = plantRef.whereEqualTo("colour", "Red")
            .get();

    Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> allTasks = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(task1, task2);
    allTasks.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
            String data = "";

            for(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : querySnapshots){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:queryDocumentSnapshots){
                    Plant plant = documentSnapshot.toObject(Plant.class);
                    plant.setDocumentID(documentSnapshot.getId());

                    String documentId =  plant.getDocumentID();

                    String name = plant.getName();
                    String bio = plant.getBio();
                    String height = plant.getHeight();
                    String colour = plant.getColour();

                    names.add(name);
                    heights.add(height);
                    colours.add(colour);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //set up the RecyclerView, setting the Layout to Horizontal, and binding the adapter
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvResults);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    resultsAdapter = new ResultsRecyclerAdapter(this, names, heights, colours);
    resultsAdapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);
}
```

Heres my ResultsRecyclerAdapter class:

```
public class ResultsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private List<String> mHeights;
    private List<String> mColours;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    public ResultsRecyclerAdapter(Context c, List<String> mData, List<String> mHeights, List <String> mColours) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.mData = mData;
        this.mHeights = mHeights;
        this.mColours = mColours;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_second_activity, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String name = mData.get(position);
        String height = mHeights.get(position);
        String colour = mColours.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(name);
        holder.tvColour.setText(height);
        holder.tvHeight.setText(colour);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvHeight;
        TextView tvColour;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvHeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
            tvColour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvColour);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ResultsRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `ResultsRecyclerAdapter` before your data is prepared inside your `OnSuccessListener`
try to update your adapter after your `onSuccess` is finished

Comment: The adapter is being updated outside the OnSuccess. Its after it. Any other tips?